# The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' while retrieveing data from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a chat application. While retrieving data from firestore I am getting an error, searched online but can't find any solution.
I am getting error in this piece of code:-

```
return SearchTile(
              username: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
              userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
          );
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

My Whole Code is

```
import 'package:chat_application_flutter/services/database.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = DatabaseMethods();

   QuerySnapshot? searchSnapshot;

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods.getUserByUserName(searchController.text).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshot!=null ? ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: searchSnapshot?.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchTile(
              username: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
              userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
          );
        },
    ) : Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Search Screen"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(87, 113, 156, 20),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        controller: searchController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Search Username...",
                            hintStyle:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                            border: InputBorder.none),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color(0x30FFFFFF),
                              Color(0x16FFFFFFF),
                            ],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                        onPressed: () {
                          initiateSearch();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    searchList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchTile({Key? key, required this.username, required this.userEmail})
      : super(key: key);

  final String username;
  final String userEmail;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24,vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(username),
              Text(userEmail),
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
            child: Text("Message"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable `searchSnapshot` is nullable, it could have a null value, so you can't just call `searchSnapshot.docs` because if `searchSnapshot` **is** null, you will get some error.

Now you already made sure the variable can't be null right here:

```
searchSnapshot!=null ? ListView.builder(
```

So we are completely safe from `searchSnapshot` being null, we know this, but dart doesn't. In order to tell dart that a nullable variable is safe to use, you can use the `!` operator, as follows:

```
username: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["name"],
          userEmail: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["email"],
```

As you can see I added a `!` between `searchSnapshot` and `.docs`, this tells dart that the `searchSnapshot` value will not be null, it would give you an error if you used this operator on a null value.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Adding a null check operator fixed the error between searchSnapshot and docs but still I am getting an error i.e redline between data() and ["name"] and the error is:- The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: The new error is basically the same, you can remove it bt adding a `!` between `data()` and `['name']`, but do keep in mind your app will crash if `data()` is null so maybe add a  `if (searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data() != null)`  somewhere?

Comment: Yeah I tried that before but it still gives an error, after more research on StackOverflow I got that `.data` is not necessary in newer version of flutter we can just write `searchSnapshot!.docs[index]["name"]`